# If cell in Col A is blank substitute with cell in Col B

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm attempting to combine two columns from another sheet into one through the `QUERY` function. My plan is to make it so if a cell in Col A is empty then a cell in Col B will be substituted.

However, due to my inexperience, I am unable to create the right formula. If anyone can help, it will be much appreciated...

Here is a diagram:

[image: Example]

I know about `IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1), Sheet1!$B1, Sheet1!$A1)` but I'm looking for an alternative method that does not require me to have to copy and paste this formula in Sheet 2 for every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple approach:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A), A:A, B:B))`

Given what is shown in your post, that would look like this:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(Sheet1!A:A), Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!B:B))`

If you want to have a directly editable header in A1, place your header in A1 and this version in A2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(Sheet1!A2:A), Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!B2:B))`